# Exposing ports on Android with React-Native

Tags: android, http, tcp, react-native

I'm trying to serve files from a React-Native app. Im using `react-native-tcp` module but when I create a TCP server it isn't on a nmap output over the mobile device ip address. I've tried with an external client with nodejs but I get ECONNREFUSED. At the same time, If I try with a client inside the react-native app and an external server, I get the same result.

I don't know if there's a protection or the module doesn't work properly. I've also the `android.permission.INTERNET` in the manifest.

Comment: Have you considered that your mobile ISP might block this? Does it work on the local address when connected to Wifi?  Only `android.permission.INTERNET`, or also `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`?